# Convert area of ASIC into kilo-gate equivalent kGE

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, asic

Is there any resource/datasheet where I can find the kilogate (kGE) of the various CMOS technologies? Essentially, I have a bunch of ASIC circuits with their areas given in mm2 that I want to convert to kGE for ease of comparison. Does the kGE/mm2 vary from manufacturer to manufacturer or is it constant?

I did find some kGE/ mm2  equivalents given in some document, but the resource it cited is no longer existent so I can't vouch for the values provided.

Thanks for clarification.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of gates per unit area is a function of many parameters, including the particular design rules for each manufacturer. If one manufacturer has more layers of interconnect than another then the effective gate density may be much higher even if the transistor geometry is very similar. The architecture and structure of the chip can also be a factor. For example, chips where a large fraction of the area is devoted to memory will have more transistors per unit area than chips that have complex processors. Manufacturers often assume that four transistors is the equivalent of a gate, which is a pretty crude metric. The bottom line is that comparing different IC manufacturers at a given process node, or the same manufacturer at different process nodes, is not very meaningful.